# Lua: string.gsub pattern in a loop lags

Tags: lua, gsub

I have 4 very large tables consisting of strings, like a thousand item each. What I need to do is loop through each table, and gsub on a large string with each string in the table.

This might explain:

```
for index, str in pairs(firstTable) do
    text = text:gsub("%f[%a]"..str.."%f[%A]", "#"..str);
end
for index, str in pairs(secondTable) do
    text = text:gsub("%f[%a]"..str.."%f[%A]", "#"..str);
end
for index, str in pairs(thirdTable) do
    text = text:gsub("%f[%a]"..str.."%f[%A]", "#"..str);
end
for index, str in pairs(fourthTable) do
    text = text:gsub("%f[%a]"..str.."%f[%A]", "#"..str);
end
```

Is there a way possible that I can somehow make it less stressful? Currently it causes massive lag when the text is very large. Thanks.

Comment: You may increase runtime performance by simplifying the regexp patterns or at least replace with more performant versions. You may try to skip leading whitespace with `"%s*("..str..")%f[%A]"`. Btw. what do you expect from `%f[%A]` frontier pattern ? It matches an empty string before `A` letter. Is that what you really want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a lookup table of all strings that need to be replaced and then do all replacements in one gsub call. The disadvantage is that you'll need to update the lookup table if contents of your four large tables change. Here is how you would create the lookup table:

```
local lookup = {}

for index, str in pairs(firstTable) do
    lookup[str] = "#" .. str
end

for index, str in pairs(secondTable) do
    lookup[str] = "#" .. str
end

for index, str in pairs(thirdTable) do
    lookup[str] = "#" .. str
end

for index, str in pairs(fourthTable) do
    lookup[str] = "#" .. str
end
```

This is how you would do the replacement:

```
text = text:gsub("%f[%a]%a+%f[%A]", lookup)
```

This should be much faster than your solution since it scans through a very large string only once instead of 4000 times. Corner-cases where this produces different results than your solution:

- I'm assuming that strings in the four tables are unique; otherwise, if a string occurs `n` times, it will be prepended with `n` hash symbols in your case and only with one in mine.
- I'm assuming the strings themselves do not contain patterns.

Both of these issues can be fixed if you need.